# вопрос по stream

Tags: java, java-stream

допустим имеется список

```
 List<String> list = Arrays.asList("add", "qwe", "add", "qwerty", "find", "qwe");
```

Хочу использовать фильтр по такому принципу:

```
list.stream().filter(x -> x.equals("add")).**то взять следующий элемент и вставить его в массив или список**
```

Comment: Удобнее циклами сделать.

Comment: А если "add" два раза подряд идёт?

Comment: Может быть `reduce` поможет. Тогда можно получить доступ к предыдущему и текущему элементу. В аккумуляторе хранить искомый список и предыдущий элемент.
Или разработать свой `Collector` для `collect`. Кажется в коллекторе тоже изощрившись можно получить доступ к двум соседним элементам.

Comment: пожалуйста, дайте вопросу более информативный заголовок (нажав [edit])

Answer (score 1):

Что-то вроде такого можно сделать:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("add", "qwe", "add", "qwerty", "find", "qwe");
List<String> res = IntStream.range(0, list.size()).
        boxed().
        filter(i -> list.get(i).equals("add")).
        map(i -> list.get(i + 1)).
        collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(res);
```